# Matrix similar to a companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, similar-matrices, companion-matrices

I am currently intensively reading my linear algebra notes under dim light and was wondering whether it is true, that a an endomorphism whose minimal polynomial has the same degree as the dimension of the vector space is similar to a companion matrix?

Comment: you are right, i corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes and we have this result:

If $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with entries from some field $K$, then the following statements are equivalent:

- $A$ is similar to the companion matrix over $K$ of its characteristic polynomial
- the characteristic polynomial of $A$ coincides with the minimal polynomial of $A$, equivalently the minimal polynomial has degree $n$
- there exists a cyclic vector $v$ in $V=K^n$  for $A$, meaning that $\{v, Av, A_2v,\ldots, A_{n−1}v\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix